# Nestjs IsEnum dto validation and swagger

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

This is working fine:

```js
    import { IsIn } from 'class-validator';
    import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

    export class createEventDto {
      @IsIn([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
      @ApiProperty({
        description: 'description of the severity property',
      })
      severity: number;
    }
```

and looks like this in swagger:
[image: swagger-number]

I am trying to understand how can I change severity type to enum, what I've tried:

```js
export enum Severity {
  Critical = 1,
  Major = 2,
  Minor = 3,
  Warning = 2,
  Info = 1,
  Clear = 0,
}
```

```js
    import { IsEnum } from 'class-validator';
    import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
    import { Severity} from '../enums/severities';

    export class createEventDto {
      @IsEnum(Severity)
      @ApiProperty({
        description: 'description of the severity property',
      })
      severity: Severity;
    }
```

Although it is working, swagger looks a bit off (example is incorrect and the description for severity in schema becomes nested in brackets:
[image: swagger-enum]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to express an enum on SwaggerUI, you need to provide `enum` property to `ApiProperty` decorator

```js
 import { IsEnum } from 'class-validator';
 import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
 import { Severity} from '../enums/severities';

 export class createEventDto {
   @IsEnum(Severity)
   @ApiProperty({
     description: 'description of the severity property',
     enum: Severity
   })
   severity: Severity;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into that doc, but that specific example somehow escaped my eyes.. :/

Comment: Actually that link now gets redirected to https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction, where there is no mention about enums. Nest's swagger integration seems to be a poorly documented topic